# What is the right way to generalize given xml to json using XSLT 1.0 without using any hardcoded elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working on the following XML document where I want to convert the XML to JSON.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
<CATEGORY>
<COUNT> 5 </COUNT>
</CATEGORY>
<TYPE>
<COUNT> 10 </COUNT>
</TYPE>
<FRUITS>
<NAME>APPLE</NAME>
<FRUIT_COUNT>10</FRUIT_COUNT>
</FRUITS>
<FRUITS>
<NAME>ORANGES</NAME>
<FRUIT_COUNT>20</FRUIT_COUNT>
</FRUITS>
</DATA>
```

The JSON I am want to convert to for the above XML looks as follows.

```
{
"CATEGORY":5,
"TYPE": 10,
"FRUITS":{
    "APPLE": 10,
    "ORANGES": 20
}
}
```

So I wrote the below XSLT code to convert the above XML to JSON.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/DATA">


<xsl:text>{"CATEGORY":</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="CATEGORY/COUNT"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

<xsl:text>"TYPE":</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="TYPE/COUNT"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

<xsl:text>
"FRUITS": {
</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="FRUITS">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
<xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="FRUIT_COUNT"/>
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>}}</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT is converting XML to JSON as expected. However I am unable to generalize the above XSLT so that if a new fields get added, I don't have to hardcode it like I did in the above XSLT. What is the right way to generalize the XSLT so that it creates the JSON without hardcoding? Is there something I am doing wrong in generalizing it?

Update:

I have tried to generalize the XSLT to convert XML to JSON using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/DATA">

<xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="/DATA">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:text>":</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output of when I used the above XSLT is as below:

```
{"CATEGORY":
 5 
,"TYPE":
 10 
,"FRUITS":
APPLE
10
,"FRUITS":
ORANGES
20
}
```

How do I generalize nested JSON such that I could get the JSON in the right format. In the converted JSON after modifying, I am getting "FRUITS" twice and it's not in the nested format like I wanted to achieve.

Comment: There many general transformations from XML to JSON, all of them making some assumptions about how to map to collections. Also there is a well documentated [`xml-to-json()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/CR-xslt-30-20170207/#func-xml-to-json) in XSLT 3.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xsl to convert xml to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122921/xsl-to-convert-xml-to-json)

Comment: @Alejandro I am using XSLT 1.0. And also, that's true about many general assumptions. This is my own customized transformation. I have provided the desired JSON format. I am just wondering if I am doing something wrong because the nested tags for Fruits isn't working as shown in desired JSON. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no right way to generalize this. You probably need to come up with a set of rules you want to implement, and use that as a basis.

1. If a child of the root element `DATA` does not have a `NAME`, output the element as a property with a name of the element name, and the text value as its value.
2. If the child does have a `NAME`, then output a single property with the name of the element name, and for all elements with the same name, output nested properties based on the `NAME`.

In this case, you could write the XSLT like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="DATA" priority="2">
  <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(NAME)]">
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
  <xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[NAME][1]">
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
  <xsl:text>": {</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="../*[name() = name(current())]">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
    <xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="*[not(self::NAME)]"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[NAME][position() > 1]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```