# XSLT: convert XML to JSON creating a group of sub nodes

Tags: json, xml, xslt

it's been days trying to perform a transformation to get a JSON file from XML documents. My xml doc have different levels of sub nodes, all examples I found on internet don't catch my case.
Here is my xml example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo id="1" group="B" />
    <foo id="2" group="A" />
    <foo id="3", group="A">
        <foo id="4" group="A" />
        <foo id="5" group="A">
            <foo id="6" group="A" />
            <foo id="7" group="A" />
            <foo id="8" group="A" />
        </foo>
    </foo>
    <foo id="9" group="A"></foo>
</root>
```

desired JSON:

```
{
    "B": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "A": {
        "id": 2
    },
    "A": [{
            "id": 4
        },
        {
            "A": [{
                    "id": 6
                },
                {
                    "id": 7
                },
                {
                    "id": 8
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "A": {
        "id": 9
    }
}
```

Means whenever I have nested `<foo>` elements, child elements are grouped with the parent element, and so on.

I tried some xsl code ([see1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122921/xsl-to-convert-xml-to-json) and [see2](https://xml2json.duttke.de/)) and failed to make them work for my case.

Comment: "all examples I found on internet don't catch my case" - programming is not just a question of finding an example on the internet that matches your case. You've got to understand the concepts so that you can adapt the examples to your case.

Comment: The "desired JSON" is not JSON at all, run it through https://jsonlint.com/ and it will tell you that having various `A` keys is not allowed.

Comment: Also what are all the commas doing in the element start tags like `<foo id="1", group="B" />`? That is not even well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//foo"/>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//foo">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=" count(ancestor::foo) = 1 and child::foo"/>
            <xsl:when test="foo[child::foo]"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@group"/><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>:<xsl:text> {&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>      &quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id/name()"/><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>:<xsl:value-of select=" concat(' ',@id)"/>
                <xsl:text>&#x0A; },</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>     
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Check this code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="foo">
            <xsl:if test="not(child::foo)">
                    <xsl:text>    "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@group"/><xsl:text>": </xsl:text><xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>        "id": </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:text>    }</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="foo">
                        <xsl:if test="not(child::foo)">
                            <xsl:text>    "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@group"/><xsl:text>": </xsl:text><xsl:if test="parent::foo"><xsl:text>[</xsl:text></xsl:if><xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text>            "id": </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:text>        },</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:text>        {</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:text>        "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@group"/><xsl:text>": </xsl:text><xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>

                           <!-- <xsl:text>        "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@group"/><xsl:text>": </xsl:text><xsl:text>[{</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>-->
                        <xsl:for-each select="foo">
                            <xsl:text>              {</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:text>                 "id": </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:text>              }</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                                <xsl:text>       ]</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                                <xsl:text>   }</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
                                <xsl:text>],</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear which result you want as the desired "JSON" has duplicated properties if there are various `foo group="A"` elements but in general of XML to JSON generation you can use XSLT 3 with support for XPath 3.1 maps and arrays (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps-and-arrays) and the `json` output method or the `xml-to-json` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-xml-to-json), that way you have two ways of creating JSON and outputting it, you can either transform your XML directly to XPath 3.1 maps/arrays and serialize them with `<xsl:output method="json"/>` or you can use the usual XSLT processing to transform your input XML to the JSON XML representation the `xml-to-json` function expects and apply it to get the JSON as text.

Here is an example of the first approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
      <xsl:map>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="foo" group-by="@group">
              <xsl:map-entry key="string(current-grouping-key())">
                  <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="not(tail(current-group()))">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:variable name="group-transform" as="map(*)*">
                              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                          </xsl:variable>
                          <xsl:sequence select="array { $group-transform }"/>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:map-entry>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:map>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:sequence select="map { 'id' : data(@id) }"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3i

And here one of the second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:sequence select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
      <map>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="foo" group-by="string(@group)">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="not(tail(current-group()))">
                      <map key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                          <string key="id">{@id}</string>
                      </map>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <array key="{current-grouping-key()}">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </array>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>          
      </map>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
      <map>
          <string key="id">{@id}</string>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3i/5

XSLT 3 is available using Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 HE for the Java platform on Sourceforge and Maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.9.1-2 and for the .NET platform  on NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/.

Comment: thank you @Martin didn't know about this approach at all. One issue when I run your code for a big file, the output is not in correct order

Comment: The second approach with `xml-to-json` should preserve the order from the original XML. Unfortunately the first approach which creates XPath maps is not able to ensure the order as the items in an XPath map don't have an order.

Comment: can you post a doc about instructions you used I want to go deep in details. Thanks in advance

Comment: @mchahoud, I have added links to the relevant spec sections.