# Read values from existing XML and populate them in Json

Tags: java, json, xml

i want to read all values in an XML file and replace them with values in a already existing JSON file by using Java.
example:

```
<Grps>
    <grp1>Red<grp1/>
    <grp2>Green<grp2/>
    <grp3>Yellow<grp3>
</Grps>
```

i want to convert the above xml in the form of json below

```
"groups":{
  "group1": "Red",
  "group2": "Green",
  "group3": "Yellow"
         }
```

Comment: convert XML to DTO then DTO to JSON

Comment: XSLT can change from XML format to any other format. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122921/xsl-to-convert-xml-to-json