# How to adjust output after parsing XML file in Java?

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing, recursion

I am trying to parse XML document by using recursive function, and I am not sure what would be the best form of data (or should I say how to save parsed document, in what form) for being able to easily convert it in JSON.
This is code:

```
private static void printNodeList(NodeList nodeList)
{

    for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) //getLength of nodeList that is passed inside of function printNodeList
    {
        Node elemNode = nodeList.item(count); //assign name of element we are currently looking at to a Node "elemNode"
        if (elemNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) //if node we are currently looking at has type ELEMENT_NODE do next block of a code
        {
            // get node name and value
            System.out.println("\nNode Name =" + elemNode.getNodeName()+ " [OPEN]");
            System.out.println("Node Content =" + elemNode.getTextContent());

            if (elemNode.hasAttributes()) //if node we are currently looking at has attributes then do this block of a code
            {
                NamedNodeMap nodeMap = elemNode.getAttributes(); //create nodeMap and pass it attributes of a node we are currently looking at
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeMap.getLength(); i++) //getLength of nodeMap or look how many attributes there is for node that we are currently watching
                {
                    Node node = nodeMap.item(i); //every attribute that is stored in nodeMap will be saved in node and his name and value will be printed out
                    System.out.println("attr name : " + node.getNodeName());
                    System.out.println("attr value : " + node.getNodeValue());
                }
            }
            if (elemNode.hasChildNodes()) //if our element (element that we are currently watching at) still has child nodes left -> recursively call "printNodeList" function
            {
                //recursive call if the node has child nodes
                printNodeList(elemNode.getChildNodes());
            }
            //output in console the name of node that we are done with
            System.out.println("Node Name =" + elemNode.getNodeName()+ " [CLOSE]");
        }
    }
}
```

[XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Zi0.png) used in code, and this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeo1Z.png) I get.
Not sure how could I lose this first "Node Content = ....." because without it, it would be cleaner and maybe easier to work with data?

The idea is to parse XML file, then save it, and then saved file convert into JSON by using some set of rules for conversion. Or maybe there is a way of doing conversion to JSON directly without need of saving parsed XML file? Maybe my whole approach to conversion from XML to JSON is wrong? Help.

Comment: I would use XSLT to convert XML to json. If you want help in doing that, can you include  your XML, examples of the expected JSON structure. Examples of xml to json via xsl are everywhere, including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122921/xsl-to-convert-xml-to-json

Comment: As I was able to understand XSLT is basically some kind of rules that you can apply on your file to change its form. That seams interesting and it might actually help me solve my problem. I don't have particular XML examples I would just like to be able to convert whatever users XML input is to JSON, and I was thinking of applying https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html this 7 patterns that might help in conversion. Is there a way of creating XSLT code that follows those rules? @BrynLewis

Answer (score 0):

I kinda figured out how to modify output a bit, but it's still missing some key points to be presented as a JSON format, so if anyone has some ideas, please feel free to share. Any help is good, thanks.
I was able to adjust output by using this:

```
public static void printNode(NodeList nList) {
    //System.out.println(nList.getLength());
    //nList.getLength() gives us cont of <> and </> under that class

    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = nList.item(i);
      

        if (node.hasChildNodes()) { //check if node has childNodes
            System.out.println("\"" + node.getNodeName() + "\":");
        }
            if(node.hasAttributes()){ //check if node have any attributes
                System.out.println("->"+node.getAttributes().item(0));
                //getAttributes() is going to get a list of attributes and we want only first one that's why we put "0" as a parameter
            }
            if(node.getChildNodes().getLength()==1){
                //if childNode length is equal to 1 that means this is a leaf node (latest node in the tree)
                System.out.println("---->"+node.getTextContent());
            }
            //recursive call
        printNode(node.getChildNodes());

    }
}
```

For [this_input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrx9N.png) I was able to get [this_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNTfn.png). I would like to try and create something more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN21i.png).